# How does Array.prototype.slice.call work in this recreation of getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a piece of code that I mostly understand. The only piece that I don't understand is how the Array.prototype.slice.call works in this instance.

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var elements = $('*').filter(function(index, node){
    // this will basically iterate through all nodes on the
    // DOM and check to see which node matches the className passed in.
    return $(node).hasClass(className);
  });
  // elements is an array of two elements. array[0] seems to be the non-enumerable
  // properties (but it has a length property?) and the other is the element on the dom. 
  // the usage below slices out array[0] and returns array[1], but since both
  // have a length property and numeric indices, why doesn't this usage return
  // both items?
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
};
```

I've left my comments/questions in-line. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :).

Thanks,
B

Comment: This looks quite silly, trying to create `getElementsByClassName` when jQuery is available…

Comment: It has the same purpose as `return elements.toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code builds a jQuery object that contains only DOM nodes that have the searched-for class. The call to `.slice()` simply makes a copy of that. It would be somewhat simpler to just

```
return elements.get();
```

which would do the same thing. (And, of course, `$("." + className)` would replace the whole thing.)

jQuery objects are not arrays. They're made to *mimic* arrays, and the `.slice()` method isn't picky; so long as the object it's working on has a `length` method and numerically-indexed properties (which jQuery  objects do), it's fine.

Comment: But the first (and second) element in the returned elements variable has a length property and numeric indices so why doesn't slice return that as well? If you console.log element before the return, you'll see both items in the array.

Comment: The array methods like `.slice()` will only operate on properties of the objects whose names are numeric.

Comment: Exactly. but array[0] has a length property, and numeric indices so why doesn't this fit the bill for slice?

Comment: @BMAC I apologize but I really don't understand what you're asking. The `.slice()` call just gets you a copy of the elements in the jQuery object as a plain array.

Comment: @BMAC if `elements` has 3 DOM nodes, then the return value will be an array with those three DOM nodes in it.

Comment: take this and paste it into your console
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var elements = $('*').filter(function(which, node){
        return $(node).hasClass(className);
      });
      console.log('ze elements', elements);
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
    };
    getElementsByClassName('topbar');
My confusion stems from what this console log is showing, which appears to be the dom element + all of its non-enumerable properties. Are you saying that slice will cut out all of these non-enumerables and return only items that fit the slice criteria?

Comment: All `.slice()` does is return a copy of part of an array; if you pass it no parameters, it returns a copy of the entire array. That's it.  When you call it with a jQuery object as the `this` value as in your example, you get back the DOM elements that comprise the jQuery object in a plain array. It's an array of DOM elements, and DOM elements have properties. I don't know what it is that you're finding to be confusing.

Comment: @BMAC in that specific example you posted in the comment, the function returns an array containing a reference to a single DOM node.

Comment: Pointy, thanks for your input and patience. I think I've got it!